# How can i make words vertical using CSS

Tags: html, css

I intend to make  vertical words using CSS here is a demo:
[image]

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
p {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
 }
```

```html
<p>I am some cool text</p>
```

`writing-mode: vertical-rl; text-orientation: mixed;`

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with text-orientation:

```css
.txt { 
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt">some text</div>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation

Answer (score 0):

just use transform and rotate

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 100px 80px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.number {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <span class="number">1</span>
    <span class="description">this is one</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="number">2</span>
    <span class="description">this is two</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="number">3</span>
    <span class="description">this is three</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need `transform: rotate` property. Here you can find more info: [enter link description here][1]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate()